# Objective C - How to make a Text View scrollable?

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have programmatically created a UITextView instance, 'textView'. I would like to make the content scrollable. I have the following code, however, the content is not scrollable:

```
self.textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(135, 87, 170, 135)];
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];
[self.textView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.textView setScrollEnabled:YES];
self.textView.scrollsToTop = YES;
self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

With the addition of the following lines of code, I am now able to scroll, but with a magnification glass showing:

```
self.textView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Is there a way to eliminate the magnification glass?

Sorry... the other additional line is:

```
self.textView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
```

Comment: You need to make sure the text inside the `UITextView` is takes up more room then the frame allows

Comment: UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView, so it should work fine. You must be doing something else wrong. Can you post more code?

Comment: Rich: The content is greater than the size of the Text View.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered my question with the code above. I am somewhat new to Apple devices and note that I am able to scroll with touch and then immediate drag. Thanks for the responses.